# How to get nth element of a list

Tags: haskell

`nth_element n list`: returns the nth element of list. Counting starts at 1. For example,
`nth_element 3 [2,5,4,6,8]` should return 4. Constraint: Define this function recursively.

My code keeps returning a null list. Please can someone help? I'm new to Haskell.
This is my code below:

```
nth_element n list =[y | (y,z) <- zip [1..] list ,z==n]
```

Comment: You violated the constraint - you are not supposed to use a list comprehension.

Comment: A little bit of renaming, `[index | (index, element) <- zip [1..] list, element == n]`, and you can spot the bug immediately. (It's still not a solution though, since you should use explicit recursion.)

Comment: @molbdnilo You kinda need to already know what the problem is to realize that that renaming would make the bug clearer. A better way to notice the bug would be to add a type signature, so that GHC can tell you the implementation doesn't match the signature.

Comment: The first part of your question seems to be an exercise. Can you make that clearer? For example by adding "I am working on this exercise:" at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

your version keeps returning an empty list because `z` for you is an element of the input-list and you compare that with `n` which should be your index - on top of that you return the indices (you more or less swapped what `zip` returns) and it will be a list even if it works.

this should fix yours:

```hs
nth_element n xs = head [ x | (i,x) <- zip [1..] xs , i == n ]
```

---

here is a non-recursive version (yours is not recursive too, so maybe this is ok even if you have this *constraint*?)

you can use [`!!`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-33--33-) for this:

```hs
nth_element n xs = xs !! (n-1)
```

here is your example:

```hs
> nth_element 3 [2,5,4,6,8]   
4
```

---

now you want it recursively so you should probably do this:

```hs
nth_element 1 (x:_) = x
nth_element n (_:xs) 
   | n > 1 = nth_element (n-1) xs
nth_element _ _ = error "out-of-range"
```

Comment: Can you do it with head and drop?

Comment: sure - `nth_element n = head . drop (n-1)` - but this too is not recursive